# Using HTML & Form helpers in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

What is the right way to use the classes HTML and FORM, from illuminate of Laravel 4 in Laravel 5?

In Laravel 4 I can use like this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) }}
    // Anything
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I can add inputs as follows:

```
{{ Form::text('username'); }}
{{ Form::text('email', 'example@gmail.com'); }}
{{ Form::password('password'); }}
{{ Form::email($name, $value = null, $attributes = array()); }}
{{ Form::file($name, $attributes = array()); }}
```

How could I do the same thing in Laravel 5?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First [install the package from **Laravel Collective**](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#installation).

Then, when you use it, be sure to use Laravel 5's new raw blade tags:

```
{!! Form::text('username') !!}
```