# php laravel form design is not working

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I am very very new to laravel framework now i want to design simple register form in laravel framework. I write a code just open form and close form but it is not working.but template design will displayed successfully

This is my form.blade.php code

```
@extends('front.template')
@section('main')
<div class="composeMailDiv">
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'compose']) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
</div>
@stop
```

I got this error "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Comment: Is the HTML being generated correctly?

Comment: Which laravel version are you using ?? Just make debug mode to true so that you can view the errors.

Comment: ok I am using Laravel Framework version 5.2.14

Comment: If you're using Laravel 5 you need to install the [Forms & HTML Package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) from Laravel Collective, as it's not part of the Laravel core anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using HTML & Form helpers in Laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958167/using-html-form-helpers-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following lines in the require section of composer.json file and run composer update `"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"`

Register the service provider in config/app.php by adding the following value into the providers array:

```
Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

Register facades by adding these two lines in the aliases array:

```
'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```